# c++ empty class size and default functions

Tags: c++, oop

http://www.careercup.com/question?id=17225664 mentions the size of empty class object is atleast 1.

So, How are default constructor, destructor, copy constructor etc incorporated in the object when it's size is so small?

Comment: You're not printing the size. Use `sizeof()`, and use C++ streams instead of `printf`

Comment: Why are you passing an `empty` to %d? That's undefined behaviour.

Comment: Ok I messed up, ignore the first part. Just answer the last part. Modified now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, How are default constructor, destructor, copy constructor etc incorporated in the object when it's size is so small?

Those are member functions, and the code for member functions does not increase the size of an object. That's just code. It doesn't get instantiated for every object you create. Adding a member function to a class doesn't increase the size of that class's instances. It is code, not data.

The code for a member function is generated once no matter how many instances of that class you create, and it acts on the particular object on which it is invoked by accessing an implicit `this` pointer which is being passed to it. In simpler terms, this expression:

```
obj.foo();
```

Is internally transformed by the compiler into this expression:

```
foo(&obj);
```

The only thing that may affect the size of a class's instance in this respect is whether your object has at least one virtual function or not; if that's the case, each object will have to store an additional pointer to its *vtable* to enable polymorphic dispatch.

Comment: if there are virtual functions then the size becomes 4 Bytes on 32 bit machine and 8 on 64 bit.

Comment: @prongs: That's because an additional pointer to the vtable needs to be stored, and addresses have a size of 4 bytes on 32 bit architectures, and 8 bytes on 64 bit architectures

Answer (score 1):

In any practical C++ implementation, non-virtual member functions (including ctors, etc.) don't form part of the object.  So they don't affect the size.<sup>*</sup>

---

<sub>*
Virtual member functions are usually implemented with a [vptr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table), which does increase the size of each object.</sub>